# Nginx remove last part in url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, digits

Sorry i'm newbie in nginx configuration, but with regexp i'm ok.

Now i'm have urls on my custom website like

`http_//domain.com/there-is-the-key?download=123456`     <--- here is digit ids at the end

And i'm tryin to hard-rewrite last part after "?", just want the keyword in the url. Here is my simple nginx config:

```
 # if ($request_method !~* ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ){return 403;}
    location ~ /\. {deny all;}


    location / {
        root       "%hostdir%";
        index      index.php;
    }

          if (!-e $request_filename) {
              rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
            #HERE I'M ADDING NEW RULE#  
              break;
         }

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
            expires     max;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return  404;
            }
```

I tried to add this one

```
rewrite ^(.*)?download.* $1 last;
```

or that

```
rewrite ^(.*)?download[^\d]$ $1 last;
```

but nothing - urls just the same.

Comment: I just want hard rewrite and remove ?download....  from any urls (without editing php code)

Comment: Query string is not a part of URI and so not a subject to change with `rewrite` directive. To get rid of query string you can use `set $args "";`. To get rid of only one of query arguments use a regexp.